# How can I give laravel route in javascript attr()?

Tags: javascript, laravel

```
$('#formid').attr('action','table/'+id);
```

I am using a form with form id 'formid' and 'id' is a variable containing id, this is the working code but I want to give route name instead of url , route is-

```
{{route('table.update',id)}}
```

Comment: You want to pass the route name or the route url using the helper `route` with the route name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just Do this

```
var url = '{{ route("table.update", ":id") }}';
url = url.replace(':id', id);

$('#formid').attr('action',url);
```

> OR

```
    var url = "{{route('table.update', '')}}"+"/"+id;
$('#formid').attr('action',url);
```